# Flowplayer playlist should start playing only after clicking Play

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I am using Flowplayer for one of my audio based website. Now I am loading the playlist clips and playing them straight away using the following code :

```
function load_clips() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'category_details/playlistXml',
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(response) {
            old_len = playlist_songs.length;
            $(response).find("song_details").each(function() {
                var song_name = "files/" + $(this).find("song_name").text();
                var song_id = $(this).find("song_id").text();
                var cat_id = $(this).find("category_id").text();
                var album_id = $(this).find("album_id").text();
                var category_id = $(this).find("category_id").text();
                playlist_songs.push({
                    url : song_name,
                    id : song_id,
                    cat_id : cat_id,
                    album_id:album_id,
                    category_id:category_id
                });
            });
            if (old_len == 0) {
                play_clip(0);
            }
  }
    });
}
```

So it is passed though the play function and it is playing the clip using the following code  :

```
function play_clip(id) {
    flowplayer().play(playlist_songs[id]);
}
```

But now I need to change this function and what I need is , the playlist has to be loaded to the player but it will play only after clicking the play button of the player. You can find my implementation at

http://bit.ly/J6hIrO

It will be great help if some one can give some sugestions